# Таблица БД не получает данные

Tags: php

Вопрос по добавлению данных в таблицу БД. Задача следующая. Пользователь на странице  dashboard вносит в форму результаты своего взвешивания и измерений(кг, содержание жира, объемы груди, талии и т.д.). Эти данные должны записываться в таблицу БД. Я создал таблицу parametrs. По логике, которую я прописал в коде, после нажатия на кнопку "Отправить" на той же странице должна происходить обработка формы и методом Post передаваться данные. Контроллер UserWeight принимает данные из формы, передает в WeightModel, где функция addParametrs добавляет значения в соответствующие ячейки таблицы parametrs. Однако кто-то в этой цепочке не может понять эту логику и данные в таблицу не приходят. Пробовал без проверки формы, и в execute принудительно цифры задавал, все равно не доходят до таблицы. (((
Уточнения: 1. Обработка формы происходит, т.к. страница обновляется; 2. Подключение к БД вынесено в отдельный файл, через который другие формы успешно взаимодействуют с другими таблицами БД.
Контроллер:

```
<?php
    class UserWeight extends Controller {
                
        public function userWeight() {

            $data = [];

            if(isset($_POST['weight'])) {
                    $user = $this->model('WeightModel');
                    $user->setData($_POST['weight'], $_POST['fat'], $_POST['visceral'], $_POST['bone'], $_POST['water'],
                                    $_POST['muscles'], $_POST['physical'], $_POST['metabolism'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['breast'],
                                    $_POST['waist'], $_POST['hips']);

//                    $isValid = $user->validForm();
//                    if($isValid == "Верно")
                        $user->addParametrs();
//                    else
//                        $data['message'] = $isValid;
                
                }
                
        $this->view('user/dashboard', $data);
    }
            
    }
```

```
Модель:

    <?php
        require 'DB.php';
    
        class WeightModel
        {
    
        private $weight;
        private $fat;
        private $visceral;
        private $bone;
        private $water;
        private $muscles;
        private $physical;
        private $metabolism;
        private $age;
        private $breast;
        private $waist;
        private $hips;
    
        private $_db = null;
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->_db = DB::getInstence();
        }
    
        public function setData($weight, $fat, $visceral, $bone, $water, $muscles, $physical, $metabolism, $age, $breast,
                                $waist, $hips)
        {
    //            $this->date = $date;
            $this->weight = $weight;
            $this->fat = $fat;
            $this->visceral = $visceral;
            $this->bone = $bone;
            $this->water = $water;
            $this->muscles = $muscles;
            $this->physical = $physical;
            $this->metabolism = $metabolism;
            $this->age = $age;
            $this->breast = $breast;
            $this->waist = $waist;
            $this->hips = $hips;
        }
    
    
        public function addParametrs()
        {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO parametrs (weight, fat, visceral, bone, water, muscles, physical, metabolism, age, breast, waist, hips) 
                        VALUES(:weight, :fat, :visceral, :bone, :water, :muscles, :physical, :metabolism, :age, :breast, :waist, :hips)';
    
            $query = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    
            $query->execute(['weight' => $this->weight, 'fat' => $this->fat, 'visceral' => $this->visceral, 'bone' => $this->bone,
                'water' => $this->water, 'muscles' => $this->muscles, 'physical' => $this->physical, 'metabolism' => $this->metabolism,
                'age' => $this->age, 'breast' => $this->breast, 'waist' => $this->waist, 'hips' => $this->hips]);
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Помоему Вы неправильно именовали параметры

```
$query->execute(['weight' => $this->weight, 'fat' => $this->fat, 'visceral' => $this->visceral, 'bone' => $this->bone,
            'water' => $this->water, 'muscles' => $this->muscles, 'physical' => $this->physical, 'metabolism' => $this->metabolism,
            'age' => $this->age, 'breast' => $this->breast, 'waist' => $this->waist, 'hips' => $this->hips]);
```

думаю должно быть так:

```
$query->execute([':weight' => $this->weight, ':fat' => $this->fat, ':visceral' => $this->visceral, ':bone' => $this->bone,
                ':water' => $this->water, ':muscles' => $this->muscles, ':physical' => $this->physical, ':metabolism' => $this->metabolism,
                ':age' => $this->age, ':breast' => $this->breast, ':waist' => $this->waist, ':hips' => $this->hips]);
```

Comment: и на основании чего вы так думаете?

Comment: на основании документации по PDOStatement

Comment: хотя оно и не должно влиять, т.к. двоеточие подставляется в ядре.

Comment: Этот вариант я тоже подозревал. Но не работает. (((

Comment: а какой результат возвращает $query->execute ?

Answer (score 0):

Позволю себе немного упорядочить Ваш код.

```php
class WeightModel
{

    private $weight;
    private $fat;
    private $visceral;
    private $bone;
    private $water;
    private $muscles;
    private $physical;
    private $metabolism;
    private $age;
    private $breast;
    private $waist;
    private $hips;

    private $_db = null;

    public function __construct( $params = array() )
    {
        if ( isset( $params ) && is_array( $params ) && count( $params ) > 0 ) {
            foreach( $params as $key => $value) {
                if ( trim( $key ) != '' && property_exists( $this, $key ) ) {
                    $this->$key = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        /** А точно `Instence`? А не `Instance` ? может тут собака и зарыта? */
        $this->_db = DB::getInstence();
    }

    public function setPropVal( $prop = null, $val = null ) {
        if ( !is_null( $prop ) && trim( $prop ) != '' && property_exists( $this, $prop) ) {
            $this->$prop = $val;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPropVal( $prop = null, $defaultVal = null ) {
        $result = $defaultVal;
        if ( !is_null( $prop ) && trim( $prop ) != '' && property_exists( $this, $prop) ) {
            $result = $this->$prop;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function save() {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO parametrs (weight, fat, visceral, bone, water, muscles, physical, metabolism, age, breast, waist, hips) 
                        VALUES(:weight, :fat, :visceral, :bone, :water, :muscles, :physical, :metabolism, :age, :breast, :waist, :hips)';

        $query = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
        /** @SanyaH прав, если у Вас модуль DB работает через PDO то ключ передается именно так как Вы его указали в запросе т.е с ":" но без кода класса DB это трудно утверждать */ 
        $query->execute([':weight' => $this->weight, ':fat' => $this->fat, ':visceral' => $this->visceral, ':bone' => $this->bone,
            ':water' => $this->water, ':muscles' => $this->muscles, ':physical' => $this->physical, ':metabolism' => $this->metabolism,
            ':age' => $this->age, ':breast' => $this->breast, ':waist' => $this->waist, ':hips' => $this->hips]);

    }
}
```

Вызов с установкой параметров

```php
$model = new WeightModel(['weight' => 100, 'fat' => 200, ... ]);
$model->save();
```

или вот так

```php
$model = ( new WeightModel())->setPropVal('weight', 100)->setPropVal('fat', 100) ... ->save();
```

А вообще судя по коду либо у Вас какая-то самописная движка с претензией на фреймворк. Либо фреймворк а-ля `Yii2` или `Laravel` который Вы неправильно используете.

Comment: Код пишу по образцам с курсов itProger. И что удивительно, по сути эта форма полностью аналогична форме регистрации нового пользователя. Разница только в количестве передаваемых параметров и их именах. Ну, насколько я разбираюсь в апельсинах. При всем этом форма регистрации работает четко, а эта форма не работает. И никаких ошибок не выдает. ((( Правда xdebug еще не применял, как тут рекомендовали выше. Надо попробовать. Может он что подскажет.

Comment: Так может Вам взять готовый фреймворк и не изобретать велосипед?

Answer (score 0):

Причину нашел, ошибку исправил, все заработало четко. Если кому интересно узнать, как я на это вышел и какие симптомы указали на ошибку, напишу в конце. А сейчас непосредственно о самой ошибке. Наверное стоит упомянуть, что проект создается по схеме MVC. Итак, часть кода, который работает правильно:
Вот параметры формы:

```
<form action="/basket/order" method="post" class="form-control">
```

Вот имя класса и метода в контроллере, который принимает и обрабатывает данные формы:

```
class Basket extends Controller
{

    public function order()
    {
        $data = [];

        if (isset($_POST['nameArr'])) {
```

Имя метода (order) указывает на тот файл страницы (order.php), от которого контроллер принимает данные. Имя класса (Basket) указывает на папку (basket), в которой этот файл находится. Поэтому имя класса должно соответствовать имени папки, а имя метода - имени файла в папке. Тогда весь код работает четко. В моем коде с ошибкой ни имя класса, ни имя метода не совпадали с адресом формы. Поэтому контроллер не реагировал на ее вопли.

Теперь, как я это обнаружил. Данные из любой формы с любой страницы без проблем передавались в БД только тогда, когда форма обрабатывалась на странице регистрации (views/user/reg.php). С любой другой страницы данные не передавались, хотя никаких ошибок не выдавалось, вызывалась одна и та же модель, одним и тем же методом контроллера, применялся один и тот же код обработки. Однако работал он только в классе User контроллера User в методе reg, который желает работать только со страницей user/reg.php. Все другие аналогичные классы напрочь игнорили данные. Обратив внимание на совпадения имени класса с именем папки и имени метода с именем файла, я попробовал все привести в соответствие и тогда все заработало шикарно.